# will HTML5 <nav> validate if the menu is imported by php include?

Tags: html

I am wondering if its ok to use the HTML5 nav-tag as a container for a menu, that is imported by PHP includes - example here:

```
<nav> 
  <?php include('includes/menu.php'); ?>     
</nav>
```

EDIT: I did test the above example placed in a simple HTML5-setup - no menu, no CSS, just the example saved as index.php - it validated with no errors in http://html5.validator.nu/

Comment: This should not be a problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: The Validator is a client like every other client – and no client cares whether the server pulled content from a static file, had it created via any scripting language – or had your granny sitting in front of a keyboard and type it in …

Comment: Thanks - i was wondering about correct use / validation, but uncertain about importing external files into HTML5-elements -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to validate your .php files, then it wont, because PHP Tags are not HTML Syntax. If you are validating the output of the PHP code after the server has delivered it as HTML, then, depending on whether your menu has correct HTML syntax, and also depending on whether you are using the HTML5 Doctype, it will validate.